# EF Core 7.0 owned properties lost during save

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I created a configuration class with an owned property:

```
public class Configuration {
    public SMSConfiguration SMS { get; set; }
}

[Owned]
public class SMSConfiguration
{
    public string From { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

When I tried to save a `Configuration` entity, it lost `SMSConfiguration` values:

```
Configuration current = DbContext.Set<Configuration>().Find(entity.Key());

EntityEntry<Configuration> attachedEntry = DbContext.Entry(current);
attachedEntry.CurrentValues.SetValues(entity); // Here doesn't copy owned properties
attachedEntry.State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Where is the problem in my code? I don't understand why lost fields.

**UPDATE**

I added this line of code:

```
attachedEntry.Reference(x => x.SMS).TargetEntry.CurrentValues.SetValues(entity.SMS);
```

Now it work but only when there is some data in one of three fields of `SMSConfiguration`. If all fields are null, it doesn't save new values.

Comment: `CurrentValues.SetValues` only sets primitive properties (int,, string etc.)

Comment: @GertArnold I always use `CurrentValues.SetValues` without problems. It works fine with objects. The problem is only on owned property.